# What do the scars on Brad Pitt's back mean in Fury?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, fury

In Fury Brad Pitt had scars on his back, which seem to be from a whip. How did he get these scars when he was in the Army and what does it show?[image: Brad Pitt]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From what I'm seeing (in my search) it seems that in the movie the backstory behind those scars is left a mystery.

From [danielsbluetape.wordpress.com](https://danielsbluetape.wordpress.com/2014/11/17/hell-hath-no-fury/)

> Minor spoiler, Norman finds out WarDaddy has some pretty bad burn
>   scars on his back. Normal movie exposition would almost demand Norman
>   ask him about this and for Brad Pitt to give a treaty eyed story as to
>   its origin. Then something great happens, he doesn’t ask him about it
>   all! Why would Norman need to ask, he has only known him for a few
>   hours, and what could he possibly say that he didn’t get from looking
>   at the scar itself

However this was not always the case, apparently.
In the original screenplay, [according to this article at Medium.com](https://medium.com/war-is-boring/the-script-for-fury-gave-norman-psychic-powers-ea4bfdaccf6c) (the draft script was originally available at [imsdb.com](http://www.imsdb.com/Movie%20Scripts/Fury%20Script.html) and the listing is still there but the script appears to have been removed), Wardaddy does give an explanation.

> The script’s version of Wardaddy isn’t just psychotic, he’s also got
>   one of those cliche tortured pasts. He tells his young crewman Norman
>   all about it.
>
> Wardaddy says that his mother was born in a town “somewhere around
>   here” in Germany. Now we know why he speaks German. **He explains how he
>   got those hideous scars on his back.** See, before the war, Collier
>   dated a girl named Rose. She was “pretty like one of those old
>   paintings.”
>
> But Wardaddy liked to drink. One night, he took Rose and his kid
>   brother—who looked just like Norman—to a county dance. He then “drank
>   two bottles of nickel whiskey and got in a punch-up at the dance with
>   this big Indian.”
>
> He knocked the big man out with an empty bottle and fled with his
>   brother and Rose. At this point, Norman interrupts him.
>
> “I’m not your bartender,” Norman says. “And I’m not you pastor. You don’t need to tell me this.” But Wardaddy can’t help but confess.
>
> **Wardaddy was drunk. He flipped the truck. It caught fire, scorching
>   his back.** His little brother and Rose died. The judge told him to join
>   the Army and die for his country.
>
> “Best advice I ever got,” Wardaddy says.